# Symfony2 OneToMany – Persist Data from embedded form

Tags: forms, symfony, one-to-many, relationship

I have a problem when I want to save data from a form to a database

I have two simple entities User and Telephone

A user can have many telephones
A telephone can have only one user

the database tables are:

> user [ id, name, email]
>
> telephone [id, user_id, phone_number]

Also my form has the following fields

- a name
- an email
- and a phone number

When I fill and submit the form, I get the following Exception

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO telephone (phone_number, user_id) VALUES (?, ?)' with params [123456, null]:
>
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'user_id' cannot be null

From the debugger bar I see 4 queries was executed

1. START TRANSACTION
2. INSERT INTO user (name, email) 
   VALUES 
   (?, ?)
   Parameters: { 1: ‘name’, 2: email@yahoogmail.com }
3. INSERT INTO telephone (phone_number, user_id) 
   VALUES 
   (?, ?)
   Parameters: { 1: 123456, 2: null }
4. ROLLBACK

I understand why this exception occurred but I don’t understand why the user_id gets NULL value.

Here is my code
(I omit getter , setters and annotations from some properties)

User Entity

```
class User
{

private $name;

private $email;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;

/** 
 * @var \Acme\FormBundle\Entity\Telephone
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Acme\FormBundle\Entity\Telephone", mappedBy="user", cascade={"ALL"})
 */
private $telephones;

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->telephones = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * Add telephones
 *
 * @param \Acme\FormBundle\Entity\Telephone $telephones
 * @return User
 */
public function addTelephone(\Acme\FormBundle\Entity\Telephone $telephones)
{
    $this->telephones[] = $telephones;
    $telephones->setUser($this);

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove telephones
 *
 * @param \Acme\FormBundle\Entity\Telephone $telephones
 */
public function removeTelephone(\Acme\FormBundle\Entity\Telephone $telephones)
{
    $this->telephones->removeElement($telephones);
}

/**
 * Get telephones
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getTelephones()
{
    return $this->telephones;
}
}
```

Telephone Entity

```
class Telephone
{
private $phoneNumber;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var \Acme\FormBundle\Entity\User
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Acme\FormBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="telephones")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $user;

/**
 * Set user
 *
 * @param \Acme\FormBundle\Entity\User $user
 * @return Telephone
 */
public function setUser(\Acme\FormBundle\Entity\User $user = null)
{
    $this->user = $user;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get user
 *
 * @return \Acme\FormBundle\Entity\User 
 */
public function getUser()
{
    return $this->user;
}
}
```

UserType

```
class UserType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('name')
        ->add('email')
        ->add('telephones', 'collection', array('type' => new TelephoneType()))
        ->add('save it', 'submit');
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Acme\FormBundle\Entity\User',
        ));
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'user';
}
}
```

TelephoneType

```
class TelephoneType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('phoneNumber');

}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Acme\FormBundle\Entity\Telephone',
        ));
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'telephone';
}
}
```

and my controller

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $user = new User();
    $Telephone1 = new Telephone(); 

    $user->getTelephones()->add($Telephone1);

    $form = $this->createForm(new UserType(), $user);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();

    }

    return $this->render('AcmeFormBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
}
}
```

Sorry for this long post

Could anyone help me?

I would appreciate it alot!

Comment: You're making a mess!
Re-read the documentation,[http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html], you'll notice that you're entering dummy code that has been put into the controller, for example, like this `$Telephone1 = new Telephone(); $user->getTelephones()->add($Telephone1);`.
And have you made ​​any changes in the methods of the entity as if it were the opposite side, but you're not saving on the opposite side!

Comment: I use the dummy code to render a collection field for entering data.
If you could help me with the mess I’ll appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I replaced

```
$user->getTelephones()->add($Telephone1);
```

with

```
$user->addTelephone($Telephone1);
```

in my controler

Answer (score 1):

It's because you use `getData()` and than `persist()` it. You should do this instead:

```
if ($form->isValid()) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($user);
    $em->flush();
}
```

Comment: In the first sentence, is `persit()` a misspelling of `persist()` ?